# SQL query to get biggest price decreases

Tags: mysql, sql

Need some help with a complicated SQL query.

We have the table pricechanges with the columns id, productid, date, price

For each productid, there are a number of rows with date = a timestamp and price = the price at the time of the timestamp.

Like this:

```
productid, date, price
3, 17/5-2016 22:00:00, 100
3, 18/5-2016 22:00:00, 120
3, 19/5-2016 22:00:00, 140
3, 20/5-2016 22:00:00, 120
3, 21/5-2016 22:00:00, 140
```

I would like to get the 10 products with the biggest price decrease in the last 7 days.

Is that possible somehow?

Thanks!

PS: It's a MySQL database.

Comment: Do you have a SQL fiddle of the system so far?

Comment: What do you means by **price decrease**? Is it price decrease if `price(7 days ago) - price(now())` > 0 ? If 7 days ago, price is 100, 3 days ago is 200, yesterday is 50, now is 80 then  **price decrease = ?**

Comment: You want to find price for product for 7 days ago and calculate difference with current price? What if product price increased 5 days ago and decreased 2 days ago? What difference you want in this case?

Comment: First, store dates using a date data type. Then get back to us.

Comment: Dates are stored as data type = datetime

Price decrease = current price < the price 7 days ago, so Pham X. Bach's example is a price decrease.

Comment: Please edit question accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF i get the logic and then tables right the try the following:

```
select d.productID from 
 (  
 select a.productid, (a.price-b.price) as priceDiff
 from products a 
 inner join products b 
 on a.productID=b.productID
 and Date(a.date)=Date(b.date)+7 
  ) d
order by priceDiff
Limit 10
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's causing a syntax error: Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table products a 
 inner join products b 
 on a.productID=b.productID
 and Date(' at line 4

Comment: I did of course replace the "products" with the real table names before giving your query a try.

Comment: if you want only the products with decrease add a where clause after 7th line: where a.price <b.price